# Javascript, go async and return to exactly the same place

Tags: javascript, node.js, interpreter

My input is javascript code that I can pre-process..

at some specific point in the middle of some function there is a token that I need to replace with some async request(e.g. async AJAX request).

On runtime: When the async request is back (the callback is being executed) I need to return to exactly the same place(with the same context) in the code where I were before executing the async call.

Is it even possible? any ideas?

note that (1) I can pre process and change the code however I had like..
(2) the token can be practically anywhere, in a loop or anywhere else.. (3) the token just represents the location of the the async call, I can parse the entire document

This code might run on a browser or via node.js

Sample code:

```
function input(num){
     num +=10;
     <token>
     return num;
}
```

Would translate to some thing like

```
function input(num){
     num +=10;
     wait(async-request(...,callback));
     return num;
}
```

**Update:** After I read your answer here is an additional question,
[Javascript: sync to async converter libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225696/javascript-sync-to-async-converter-libs)

Comment: going to need some sample `\\code` here to better assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several projects that attempt to rewrite code written in a synchronous pattern into async code using continuations. E.g. you might want to take a look at:

https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs

Some patterns (loops, try/catches) likely present more challenges than simple linear flow, but I'm pretty sure it's a solvable problem in the general case. I don't think you'll be able to do it with simple token replacement, though -- you'll need to parse the javascript and transform it.

Comment: streamlinejs: can you explain how does the _ works? is it really async? does other code run while we are waiting for the callback?

Comment: [Stormjs](https://github.com/guileen/stormjs) achieves a similar thing. It's all black magic ;) avoid it.

Comment: @ciochPep any sort of transformation like that needs some knowledge of the functions it is working with -- whether they're sync or async, and if async which function is the callback (and, unless you assume conventions, what the signature of the callback is). I'm not too familiar with streamline, but I gather that the _ serves as a marker of where the callback is.

Answer (score 2):

To best achieve this is to divide your code into two pieces.  We'll call the whole thing function `f`, everything up to and including the async call is `F1()`, while everything that needs to happen once the async result is achieved is `F2()`.

What you need to do is execute `F1()`, who's last command is to make the asynchronous call.  `F1()` is now done and should return processing to main.

However the callback from the async call should (1) process the incoming data into a structure (or whatever you have in mind) and then (2) call `F2()` supplying this new data.

It's the curse/beauty of async - you cannot hold up the synchronous code while you wait for the reply so you have to change your structure such that dependent pieces of code are called once the async reply is received.

*Update from your example:*
Because of async you have to change your way of thinking on return data and consumption too.  Say your calling code was:

```
var b=input(2);
```

That's not gonna fly with an async call in the middle.  Instead you'd need something like:

```
var b;
getInput(2);

function getInput(num) {
  num+=10;
  async-request(...,/*callback=*/supplyNum);
}
function supplyNum(reply) {
  b=reply;
}
```

(this is an example - I *totally* don't recommend using global variables but you hopefully get the idea).  I skipped over with what to do with `num` from `getInput` - given you're waiting for the `async-request` presumably it could receive `num` as an argument so it's answer would be a relevant modification.  In all likelihood you're just giving an example, but thought I should mention it ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript, go async and return to exactly the same place…

This is called `synchronous code` and is the antithesis to async.

Really what you need is a blocking call.

Comment: Yay, thanks random anonymous downvoter with no reason given. This dev really is asking how to do things synchronously but call it async.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested, but you could try something like this:

```
function sleep(delay)
{
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}


function waitforAsync(url, callback) {

  var done = false;

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", url, true)
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState != 4) { return; }
      callback(req.responseText);
      done = true;
  };
  req.send(null);

  while (not done) {
      sleep(1000);
  }
}


function input(num){
    num +=10;
    waitforAsync(url, callback);
    return num;
 }
```

Comment: While your `sleep` function will work, it'll also cause 100% processor usage and cause blocking - preventing other JS code from executing (or severely decreasing performance).  In a browser anyway.

Comment: @Rudu: I assumed that, but question is asking to: make asynchronous call...but pause current execution until it returns.  ...this just seemed like the simplest way (but agreed that I certainly wouldn't recommend it in a general sense).